# Proof that eigenvalues of $(\hat{L^+})^n (\hat{L})^n ≥ 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Hilbert space $\mathbb{L^2}$. So my thoughts:

$n=0$ - true.
Let $\hat\alpha = (\hat{L^+})^n (\hat{L})^n $

For $n+1$: $\ \hat{L^+} \hat\alpha \hat{L} \phi = \lambda \phi = \hat\alpha \phi$ since its just unitary. But for $n=0$ eigenvalues are just $1$, no? So following my proof for $(\hat{L^+})^n (\hat{L})^n$ eigenvalues are $1$ too.

upd: which are false as I can see from now.

Comment: Which Hilbert space? What's $\hat L$? Is $\ ^+$ taking the adjoint?

Comment: @Roland There were nothing much about space in the task, but lets assume its $\mathbb{L}^2$. $\hat{L}$ is some linear operator on that space. Yes, $^+$ means adjoint. I guess I need to use $^\dagger$

Comment: I don't see where you get unitarity from. What if $\hat L$ has a kernel?

Comment: @Roland, ok I guess I forgot that I need $\hat{L}$ to be unitary, damn. Then I have no idea of proof yet. There is nothing said about $\hat{L}$, its just any operator.

Comment: The claim is false for $L:x \mapsto 0$, or any operator with a kernel, for instance $f \mapsto -f''$ on the Hilbert space $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ (domain is given by sufficiently often differentiable functions)

Comment: @Roland, so $L cos(x) = cos(x)$ and 1 is eigenvalue. I am misunderstanding something, aren't I? But ye, if i'll take $f \mapsto 2f''$ for example, ill get -2 as eigenvalue. So I need to have empty kernel? There's nothing really said in the book, but its QM books so no clue.

Comment: This is true, but the derivative of a constant function is zero, so $L x = 0$, i.e. $0$ is a nonpositive eigenvalue.

Comment: @Roland, anyway even if the kernel is empty, which excludes constant functions, I have $f \mapsto 2f''$ with eigenvalue -2, no?

Comment: The updated statement is false for any nonzero operator. Maybe you just want $L^* L \ge 0$, or $L^* L > 0$ for an operator with a trivial kernel?

Comment: @SashoNikolov just typo. I mean ≥. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction. Base case $n=0$ is trival. Set $M = (L^*)^{n-1} L^{n-1}$. $M \ge 0$ by the induction hypothesis. We have $(L^*)^{n} L^{n} = L^* M L$, and
$$
\langle L^* MLx, x\rangle = \langle M(Lx), Lx\rangle \ge 0,
$$
which finishes the inductive step.

Comment: Sorry, but is $\lambda = \langle \hat L x , x \rangle$?

Comment: I am not sure what your notation is. If $x$ is an unit eigenvector with eigenvalues $\lambda$, then, yes, you are right. The definition of a positive semidefinite operator that I am familiar with is that $M \ge 0$ if and only if $M$ is self-adjoint and for every $x$, $\langle Mx, x \rangle \ge 0$.

Comment: The question was to proof that all the eigenvalues of that operator are non-negative.  So my notation is like $\lambda$ for any eigenvalue and $\phi$ for eigenfunction (eigenvector).

Comment: Well, in that case, take $\phi$ to be an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and norm 1, from the proof above you have that $0 \le \langle M\phi, \phi \rangle = \langle \lambda \phi, \phi \rangle = \lambda$

Comment: yep I got it already. Thank you.